# Solving a system of eqns. by variation of parameters - When the Wronskian is 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametrization, wronskian

I have the system:

$x'(t)=3x+2y+2e^{-t}$

$y'(t)=-2x+y+e^{-t}$

which I solve as:

$x'-3x+2y=2e^{-t}$

$-2x+y'+y=e^{-t}$

which gives:

$(D-3)x+2y=2e^{-t}$

$-2x+(D+1)y=e^{-t}$

We multiply the uper eqn. by 2, and the lower by (D-3) to eliminate the x terms:

$4y+(D^2-2D-3)y=3^{-t}$

Since D is the differential operator, this gives the equation:

$y''-2y'+y=3e^{-t}$

The general solution of this is simply

$q=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4-4}}{2}=1$

which we plug in the form $y(t)=ce^{qt}\longrightarrow ce^t$.

2. Now we have to find the specific solution, but the Wronskian, based on the two components of the general solution $c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)$:

W=\begin{vmatrix}
y_1(x) & y_2(x)\\
y_1'(x) & y_2'(x)
\end{vmatrix}

is based (un)fortunately on only one function, that is $ce^t$. So the Wronskian (determinant of this matrix) is 0.

So how do I proceed by variation of parameters when W=0?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a flaw in your reasoning, because there are two linear independent solutions. The first one is the one you've already found, but since the operator has multiple roots, the general solution in this case is $c_1e^t + c_2te^t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y''-2y'+y=3e^{-t}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(y(t)e^{-t})''=3e^{-2t}$$
Integrate twice.

---

Note that the Wronskian is not zero:
$$y_1(t)=e^t  \implies y_2(t)=te^t$$
$$W(y_1,y_2)=W(e^t,te^t)$$
$$W(e^t,te^t)=e^t(e^t+te^t)-te^{2y}=e^{2t}$$